# Qmqtt QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'ClientState' (Make sure 'ClientState' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

Tags: qt, c++11, mqtt

I am creating a thread and inside that thread :

```
m_client = new QMqttClient(this);
m_client->setHostname("ps01.xx.com");
m_client->setPort(1883);
m_client->setClientId("Sas-RASPi-001");

m_client->connectToHost();
```

connecting to the mqt broker.

any signal connecting attempt like :

```
QObject::connect(m_client, &QMqttClient::stateChanged, this, &Messenqt::updateLogStateChange);
```

produce an error like :

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'ClientState'
>   (Make sure 'ClientState' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

I added :

```
 qRegisterMetaType<QMqttClient::ClientState>("QMqttClient::ClientState");
```

in the beginning of the code (above code)

still same problem.

What is the proper way to use mqt from different thread in QT signal/slot way ?

**EDIT:**

```
for (int i = 20 ; i < 20 ; i++){
QThread::sleep(1);
if(m_client->publish(topic_, QString("testing. . . ").toLocal8Bit() , 1 ,true) == -1;
      qDebug() << " error" <<;
}
```

Hi,
I am using qmqtt in a for loop with sleep 1 second and then process waiting to send messages until all 20 messages published.
When the loop finishe all 20 messages send .

But . if we will not use QThread::sleep(1) . then each messages sending individually. why . ?

Is there any way to force send to each messages immediatelly when its published?

**EDIT 2**

Below example not sending the images to the broker. It is blocking some place somewhere. I need flush the messages :)

minimal example :

```
 m_client = new QMqttClient(this);

m_client->setHostname("ps01.xxx.com");
m_client->setPort(1883);
m_client->setClientId("RASPBERRY-009");

m_client->setUsername("vv");
m_client->setPassword("vv");
m_client->setCleanSession(false);

m_client->connectToHost();
//yeni slot mekanizmasi. kendi icinde &Publisher örneği..
QObject::connect(m_client, &QMqttClient::stateChanged, this, &Publisher::updateStateChange);

QObject::connect(m_client, &QMqttClient::connected, this, &Publisher::sendMessages);
```

an the send message:

```
 void Publisher::sendMessages()
{
    QDir dir("/ram");
    int count = 0;
    QThread::sleep(5);

    while (true){
        QStringList images_metas = dir.entryList(QStringList() << "*.png" ,QDir::Files);

        if (images_metas.size() > 0){

            foreach(QString filename, images_metas) {

                dataLoad *dl = new dataLoad;
                QString  img_path = "/ram/" + filename;
                QImage img(img_path);


                qDebug() << " : : : " << QImage("/ram/00-02-2018-04-05-2.png").size() << endl;


                dl->image = img;
                dl->text = "Deneme MEsajıdır . . ";
                QByteArray byteArray_;

                QDataStream stream(&byteArray_, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
                stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_10);

                stream << dl->image << dl->text;

                qDebug() << count++ << "  sending  : " << byteArray_.size() << "  " <<  filename << endl;

                qDebug() << testPublish(byteArray_)<< endl;

            }

        }
        else {
            qDebug() << " folder is empty waiting... " << endl;
        }
        //Check every 1 second
        QThread::sleep(1);
    }

}
```

and the publishing:

```
    qint32 Publisher::testPublish(QByteArray &bytarray)
{
    QMqttTopicName topic_ = QString("qtmqtt/topic1");
    QString mesaj = ".x.x.x.x.x.x.x.";

        auto id = m_client->publish(topic_, mesaj.toLocal8Bit() , 1 ,true);

        return id;
}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why do you want to implement a thread for QtMqtt ?, QtMqtt is done so that there is no need to use threads since it sends you the information through signals.

Comment: You right I tried and succesfull. bur when I put some extra QThread::sleep it is waiting to finish all submissing to publish. I Edited above you can take a look.

Comment: Are you using a Thread only to send 20 messages where each message should be sent one second after the other?

Comment: What does *sending  individually* mean?

Comment: No , last example not threaded. it is a for  loop to test. Qmqtt waiting to finish all 20 messages published that sending the server. If I remove sleep(1) line. than each message sending immediatelly in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
msg_timer = new QTimer(this);

//TODO big chip save timer.
connect(msg_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()) , this , SLOT(sendMessages()));
msg_timer->start(1000);
```

dont use while loop. It is blocking everything..

Best

Comment: Thanks a lot..  this is what I concluded and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I get a solution to the problem of "Qmqtt QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'ClientState' (Make sure 'ClientState' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)" caused by working in threads. Although I have not made clear the specific meaning, at least it can work well.

You can try it:

```
 connect(m_client, &QMqttClient::stateChanged, [&](QMqttClient::ClientState state){
    qDebug()<< state;
});
```